# How to get data fast from database for more than 10 000 records in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, web-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to bind data from a table and I have more than 10 000 records in the table. I have a problem in binding data in `ListView` when the page is re-load at that time it taking so much time to bind.

I want to bind very fast.

I tried binding using Web Services and retrieving only required field but did not speed up.

```
public class getHistoryPoperty : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

[WebMethod]
public DataTable Get()
{
        string conString= ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {


            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select m.intPlotid,m.strwant,m.strPlotName,m.intTotalPrice,m.strOwnerName,c.strCityName,cat.strCategoryName,s.strSubCategoryName,d.strDistrictName,t.strTalukaName,a.strAreaName,a1.strName,a2.strName from PropertyMaster as m left outer join tblCity as c on m.intCityId=c.intCityId left outer join tblCategory as cat on m.intCategoryId=cat.intCategoryId left outer join tblSubCategory as s on m.intSubCategoryId=s.intSubCategoryId left outer join tblDistrict as d on m.intDistrictId=d.intDistrictId left outer join tblTaluka as t on m.intTalukaId=t.intTalukaId left outer join tblArea as a on m.intAreaId=a.intAreaId left outer join tblAreaTypeMaster as a1 on m.intAreaTypeId=a1.intAreaTypeId left outer join tblAreaTypeMaster as a2 on m.intAreaTypeId1=a2.intAreaTypeId where m.bitIsActive=0 order by m.intPlotId desc ", con))
            {


                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        dt.TableName = "MyTableName";
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        return dt;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
}
```

Comment: Please include the query plan also. What is slow here? Is it really the query or handling the data or transporting it to the user? Is the user really shown over 10k records or only some?

Comment: Showing 10K records to the user to select from is not a good idea. You should provide user to select search criteria to limit the amount of data being queried and displayed in the UI.

Comment: Binding  is slow when page is open. Yes all records i have to show. Query is passed in sql command.

Comment: What does a user do confronted with 10,000 records? Browse?

Comment: Hello @Mary, Its used in admin side not in user side.

Comment: Why can't you use paging? Scrolling through 10000 records will be a nightmare on a single page. It defeats the purpose of paging.

Comment: Hello @mdowes, paging already used.

Comment: @DhavalGhevariya, paging could be used in 2 ways, client side and server side. In this context, the client is the business logic code and server is the database. Why don't you ask the database for the first 100 records, then the next 100 when the user clicks on the next page and so on. No need to pull all the records from the DB in one shot and then use paging from server's memory.

Comment: @mdowes paging is used using bootstrapped data table.

Comment: `sda.Fill(dt);` will dump entire contents of sql table in your datatable which essentially means all 10k records will be returned by the query. To avoid it use `sda.Fill(currentIndex, pageSize, dt);`. Here pageSize is the no of records returned for a page (e.g. 100) and currentIndex needs to be updated everytime with the page number the user requests (for e.g. if user requests for 5th page then you need to show records from 401-500)

Comment: What should be the steps while exporting data ?? We can't do page wise export right!!!